# CREATE Sql Server VIEW from multiple tables GROUPing BY, SELECTing subqueries AS aliases

Tags: sql-server, view, group-by, subquery, multiple-tables

Building on this post: [MS Version of This MySQL View with GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239820/ms-version-of-this-mysql-view-with-group-by)

How can subqueries be added?

All I want is to add to that view is an alias from a SELECT as an alias like:

```
... AS table2column2, (SELECT column1 FROM dbo.table3 WHERE constant = 1) AS table3column1, ...
```

Yes, I've looked everywhere.  Interwebs have nada.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically correct, just add a `TOP 1` , as you cannot return more than one value:

```
(SELECT top 1 column1 FROM dbo.table3 WHERE constant = 1)
```