# Update table using other two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sum

I have three tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

What I want is to update table `t1` with  `t1.Quantity= sum(t2.quantity) - sum(t3.quantity)
 where id= $_POST['id']`

HOW TO WRITE QUERY FOR THIS.

I tried this one.. but its not working.

```
 INSERT INTO Products
   ( `ProductID`, `ProductName`, `TotalQuantity`,
     `TotalPrice`, `DateOfLastupdate` )
 values
  ( '$ProductID', '$ProductName', '$Quantity',
    '$TotalPrice', '$PurchaseDate' )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
   UPDATE Products.TotalQuantity =
     ( select sum(Products_Purchased.Quantity) from Products_Purchased
       where ProductID = '$ProductID' )
     - ( select sum(Products_Sold.Quantity) from Products_Sold 
           where ProductID = '$ProductID' )
```

Comment: if record is not exists,then it should be inserted else  should be updated.. thats  why i m using insert on duplicate key

Answer (score 0):

May it helps

UPDATE table1, table2 
SET table1.column1 = 
(
    SELECT SUM( 
        (SELECT constant FROM table3) +
        (SELECT table2.sum_number *** WHERE table2.table2_id1 = table1.id) 
    ) 
) 
WHERE table1.id = table2.table2_id1;

[UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SUM(table2{& table3} WHERE table2_id1 = id1) WHERE id1 = table2_id1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755925/update-table1-set-column1-sumtable2-table3-where-table2-id1-id1-where?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update products t1,
(select productid,sum(Products_Purchased.Quantity) as x from Products_Purchased
   group by productid having ProductID = '$ProductID' ) t2,
(select productid,sum(Products_Sold.Quantity) as y from Products_Sold 
   group by productid having ProductID = '$ProductID' ) t3
 set TotalQuantity=t2.x-t3.y where t1.ProductID = '$ProductID' 
      and t1.productid=t2.productid and t1.productid=t3.productid
```

Comment: but can i use the same statement with insert on duplicate key ?

Comment: should be can.. just try in your development :D